# Navegação via teclado

Tags: html, acessibilidade

Comecei a desenvolver um projeto, que tem algumas necessidades de navegação via teclado, pois é um site municipal, no caso deve ser acessível para deficientes também.

Estou um pouco perdido em como começar, ou pelo que pesquisar, inicialmente tenho o seguinte menu:

[image: SS]

Fiz da seguinte forma para o menu:

```
<nav class="nav-access">
    <a href="#content" accesskey="1">Ir para o conteúdo</a>
    <a href="#nav" accesskey="2">Ir para o menu</a>
    <a href="#contrast" accesskey="3">Alto Contraste</a>
</nav>
```

Que deve ter a funcionalidade de navegação pelos números do teclado, sugestões de funcionalidades? ou técnicas para este tipo de navegação.

Comment: A sua dúvida não esta clara. Tu quer saber como fazer isso funcionar ou quer sugestões de funcionalidades?

Comment: Sugestões de funcionalidades, realmente, ficou um pouco confusa a pergunta.

Comment: Você quer que as pessoas opinem sobre o que você deveria por na sua aplicação?

Comment: Inicialmente, realmente estava com dúvida de como fazer, pois não conhecia "accesskey" e "tabindex", mas pode ser de utilidade para outras pessoas está dúvida.

Comment: `accesskey` não é um atributo HTML5, a única diferença dele no HTML5 para o HTML4.01 é que no HTML4.01 apenas as tags `<a>`, `<area>`, `<button>`, `<input>`, `<label>`, `<legend>`, e `<textarea>` suportam ele, como você está está a usar a TAG `<a>`, então determino que não existe necessidade da "tag" `HTML5` na questão.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o próprio accesskey mesmo mas precisa mostrar para o usuário como acessá-lo, seja por áudio ou alguma legenda explicando como usar em cada navegador/SO.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_accesskey.asp

Comment: Estou utilizando como referência o site do planalto: http://www2.planalto.gov.br a navegação utilizando "tab" também fica certinha

Comment: Então acho que fica bom do jeito que está lá no site do planalto mesmo, você pode até colocar um plugin JQuery pra fazer um efeito de scroll. Mas tem que explicar como usar (no caso do planalto ele nao fala que no Chrome tem que usar Alt+número do conteudo).